# CLI build Config.xml phonegap 3.3.0 ignores name and description

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

In the config file that is the blue print for all platforms, i Have added this:

```
<name>My app name</name>
<description>
    My app description.
</description>
<author email="my email" href="my url">
    Same name
</author>
```

But after running

```
phonegap run android
```

In the config.xml in the folder platforms/android/res/xml it gives:

on top of the file:

```
<name>Hello Cordova</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
```

than the feature list

and than (before the preferences):

```
<name>My app name</name>
<description>
    My app description.
</description>
<author email="my email" href="my url">
    Same name
</author>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
```

So it does copy the name etc in the config file... but somehow leaves the example name in the config file.

**Edit 16-jan-2014**

Although this question: [Config.xml ignored in creation process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792787/config-xml-ignored-in-creation-process) is about and the html reference... it look's like there is still a lot work to do for the command line option that creates the platform folders... so my attempt to make evrything work (both ios and android) from 1 www folder looks like a mission impossible right now.

For developing this is a mess... some things (plugins) you have to do from command line... and do a build to get the proper config... but than all the mistakes you have recovered manually... will be overwritten again!

**Edit 12-feb-2014**

by the way, in my total quest in this phonegap new way of living... I have another very long question and asnwering: [Upgrade to phonegap 3.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923738/upgrade-to-phonegap-3-3-0)

**Edit 5 may 2014**

Due to all problems in phonegap, the benefits of the principle behind phonegap has gone for me. (I still believe in potential phonegap can be the solution... but for now it's to premature). So I Am sorry i have to leave the phonegap path. I let this answer open for the ones still searching for answers... but do not expect any answers or the 'acceptance of the right answer' from me.

Comment: Funny thing: in /platforms/android/assets/www/config.xml project name and description are actual. But instead plugin list is empty

Comment: @AndreyShustariov You know you have to add plugins using phonegap plugin add... and than run the phonegap build android command ? see another question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923738/upgrade-to-phonegap-3-3-0

Comment: I so agree with your comment about it being premature!!

Answer (score 3):

The answer of christianmenkens on this question: [Cordova Android Plugin: config.xml overwritten by cordova prepare?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283265/cordova-android-plugin-config-xml-overwritten-by-cordova-prepare) gives some more insight in my problem here...

He describes 3 config.xml files.
What I call the 'blue print' config.xml file, is his number 1 file. (the only one that should 
be edited according to the docs of phonegap....

1) myproject/www/config.xml

but he mentions 2 other config.xml:

2) myproject/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml

3) myproject/platforms/android/assets/www/config.xml

it looks as if the name and description problem I describe above only appears in file nr. 2
In file nr. 3 everything seems ok... well the name and description part.... because all other things I expect to go automatically is still very messy.

My onlu conclusing: a lot of bugs still in this whole procedure...

Answer (score 1):

I just see this blog: http://devgirl.org/2014/02/10/3-cordova-cli-changes/
Might have to look at this new Cordova upgrade

Answer (score 0):

try moving your config.xml from the www folder to the root folder of the project, that worked for me.

New files structure will be.

```
merges/
platforms/
www/
config.xml
```